# Magento 2 some urls redirected to specific store view

Tags: magento2, redirect, store-view

I have 2 websites and three store views set up in my mangento 2 :

- domain.nl
- domain.be
- domain.be/fr/

I dont know for some reason,  some urls in front-end and back-end get redirected to `domain.be/fr/`. either its a product url, search result, admin grid url, or 404 page (not all urls) some of them get 302 redirect to FR site.

by the way, we dont have any special url rewrite about this from magento admin or server configuration.

[image]

has anyone ever experienced this?

environment :

- Magento 2.2.9
- nginx
- php 7.0.33